# Process ended by signal 5

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am getting following error `Process ended by signal 5`, Does anybody know what this error means on AS400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears to be due to exceeding the number or length of arguments or environment variables:

[IBM: Argument Number Limits for ls, rm, and other Qshell Commands - "qsh: 001-0078 Process ended by signal 5"](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=nas1dda70889f2ada67c862577cb00566e4a)

Can you provide more context for when you are receiving the error and the last few lines of the job log?